# Why isn't that variable declared at the header file?

Tags: objective-c

According to Stanford University Objective-C course Fall 2010/2011, lecture 3:

```
typedef struct {
    float x;
    float y;
} Point;

@interface Bomb
@property Point position;
@end

@interface Ship : Vehicle {
    float width, height;
    Point center;
}

@property float width;
@property float height;
@property Point center;
- (BOOL)getsHitByBomb:(Bomb *)bomb;
@end

@implementation Ship

@synthesize width, height, center;

- (BOOL)getsHitByBomb:(Bomb *)bomb
{
    float leftEdge = self.center.x - self.width/2;
    float rightEdge = ...;

    return ((bomb.position.x >= leftEdge) &&
        (bomb.position.x <= rightEdge) &&
        (bomb.position.y >= topEdge) &&
        (bomb.position.y <= bottomEdge));

}

@end
```

Why aren't float leftEdge and float rightEdge there at the interface?

Also, the return case, it means that if all those cases are right then it returns YES, if not then NO (or 1 if cases are true, 0 if false). Right?

Comment: You are correct on the return case.  If all the '&&' were replace by '||' it would return true if any of the conditions were true.  The '&&' ensures that it only returns true if all the conditions are true (which in this case, means the bomb hit the ship).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`leftEdge` and `rightEdge` are not in the interface because they're local variables. They are **only** needed in that function.

On your second question, you are right. That's exactly the case.

You only put variables on the interface (class) when you need to make them part of the object being represented by it. Example: if your interface represents a vehicle, then probably `numberOfWheels` will be a interface (class) variable. When you only need a variable in a certain scope (a function) to do a temporary calculation (like `leftEdge` and `rightEdge` in your example) then all you need is a local variable.

Comment: Can you clarify it more by specifying which variables exactly are to be written at the interface?

Comment: @TheNavigator: updated my answer with **some** clarification. hope it helps. good luck fellow!

Comment: Hehehe, you stole the tick mark from Ryan :P

Okay thanks much. That's even more clarified :)

Answer (score 4):

There's a difference between local variables and member variables. The member variables are "global" to the class and can be referenced from any instance method since they are part of the interface. `leftEdge` and `rightEdge` are both local variables and are declared in the `getsHitByBomb:` method. They go out of scope as soon as the method returns/exits.

Comment: That's more easy to be understood. Thank you Ryan, you solved it for me :)